# Grouping points into user-provided number of clusters using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clustering

I am looking for a process in ArcGIS that takes a point feature class and groups the points into a user-provided number of clusters.

Comment: Have you explored the questions associated with the [tag:clustering] tag?

Comment: @whuber I poked around for a while on the stack exchange without much luck.  I'll explore and let you know what I find

Comment: I found a bunch of good answers here.  Perhaps more to the point, a brief survey of the variety of cluster-related *questions* will suggest the additional information you should be supplying to get a good solution to your problem.

Comment: I didn't find anything directly corresponding to what I'm looking for.  However, [Clusterpy](http://code.google.com/p/clusterpy/) has provided me with the impetus to just go ahead and try and script a solution in Python anyway.  I find it strange that there's no obvious tool/solution for this in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 5):

k-means clustering is exactly what you want.
Version 10.1 has k-means clustering... if you are beta program eligible you could try that.
You could also try doing your k-means clustering in R and then bringing the results over the arcgis.
I think there are also some 3rd party scripts out there for k-means clustering using versions 9.3 and 10.0 too.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.  I'll snoop around and see what 3rd party scripts I can find.

Comment: Have a look at Geospatial Modelling Environment (GME)  - http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/kmeans.htm It requires ArcGIS 10.X and R.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is attributed with some sort of "by type" field, you could use the Mean Center geoprocessing tool and set the case field.

Comment: @ Hornbydd, good suggestion.  However, I'm looking for a method to group points based on geographical proximity only.  Thanks though.

Comment: It is very useful this geoprocessing tool.